# Rails validate associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to prevent users from creating duplicate chatrooms (chatroom includes 2 users). But I have no idea how to validate if chatroom with the same users already exists before save.

---

Thats my create method in chatroom controller:

```
 def create
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new
    @friend = User.where(username: params[:friend]).last

    @chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: @friend, chatroom: @chatroom)
    @chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: current_user, chatroom: @chatroom)

    if @chatroom.save
      flash[:notice] = "chatrooom created"
      redirect_to @chatroom
    else
      flash[:notice] = "chatrooom not created lol"
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    end
 end
```

And that is how I am trying to validate if there is no chatroom with 2 users like the new one:

In my class **Chatroom**

```
after_save :duplicate?

  # Checks if chatroom containing specific users exists.
  def duplicate?
    user = self.users.first
    friend = self.users.second

    # lines below work fine - they check if there is already such chatroom
    (Chatroom.all - [self]).each do |chatroom|
      if ((chatroom.users & [user, friend]) - [user, friend]).empty?
        self.errors.add(:chatroom, "Such chatroom already exists.")
      end
    end

  end
```

**The problem is:** if I use `after_save` in validating method I can get the self.users.first to set user and friend variables, but then It does not stop from creating that record and I am not sure If deleting it there is a good idea. Secondly - I use `validate` instead of `after_save` self.users.first and self.users.second returns nil, so I can't check for duplicates.

**PS:** I do not want to have users id as the attributes in the chatrooms table because I want to add ability to connect to chat for as many ppl as you want.

Comment: surely `self.users.first` and `self.users.second` are nil before save but can't you validate  `user_id` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
  def duplicate?
    is_duplicate = (Chatroom.all.to_a - [self]).any? do |chatroom|
      chatroom.users.map(&:id).sort == self.chatroom_users.map(&:user_id).sort
    end

    if is_duplicate
      errors.add(:chatroom, "Such chatroom already exists.")
    end
  end
```

Here are all of the models.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chatroom_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :chatroom_users

  before_validation :duplicate?

  def duplicate?
    is_duplicate = (Chatroom.all.to_a - [self]).any? do |chatroom|
      chatroom.users.map(&:id).sort == self.chatroom_users.map(&:user_id).sort
    end

    if is_duplicate
      errors.add(:chatroom, "Such chatroom already exists.")
    end
  end
end

class ChatroomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chatroom_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :chatrooms, :through => :chatroom_users
end
```

And here is a test

```
require 'test_helper'

class ChatroomTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  test 'does not allow duplicate chatrooms' do
    first_user = User.create!
    second_user = User.create!

    chatroom = Chatroom.create!
    chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: first_user, chatroom: chatroom)
    chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: second_user, chatroom: chatroom)
    chatroom.save!

    duplicate_chatroom = Chatroom.create!
    duplicate_chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: first_user, chatroom: chatroom)
    duplicate_chatroom.chatroom_users.build(user: second_user, chatroom: chatroom)

    assert !duplicate_chatroom.valid?
  end
end
```

Note: This code is in Rails 5.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank You for this great answer. I just wonder - why it works now, but with `chatroom.users.map(&:id).sort == self.users.map(&:id).sort` it does not?

Comment: That doesn't work because user ids are not persisted yet so the association doesn't work yet. But user_id works because those are stored on the model.